# Timestamp too large for datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Why can I not convert the following timestamp?

```
from datetime import date

timestamp = date.fromtimestamp(1571266800000000000)
print("Date =", timestamp)
```

https://www.epochconverter.com/ gives the right result.

Comment: `.fromtimestamp()` expects seconds, not nanoseconds. Try `date.fromtimestamp(1571266800000000000/1e9)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the nanoseconds, there is another caveat here: If I run

```
from datetime import date
timestamp = date.fromtimestamp(1571266800000000000/1e9)
print("Date =", timestamp)
>>> Date = 2019-10-17
```

note that this gives me the date in my ***local timezone*** (UTC+2). However, if you expect the date to refer to UTC (since seconds since the epoch *should* refer to UTC), you need to set the `tzinfo` property:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(1571266800000000000/1e9, tz=timezone.utc)
print("Date =", timestamp.date())
>>> Date = 2019-10-16
```

Answer (score 0):

Python expects seconds. The epochconverter gives me

> Assuming that this timestamp is in nanoseconds (1 billionth of a
> second): GMT: Wednesday, 16. October 2019 23:00:00 Your time zone:
> Donnerstag, 17. Oktober 2019 01:00:00 GMT+02:00 DST Relative: 9 months
> ago

So I think what you should use in Python is:

```
date.fromtimestamp(15712668)
```

Comment: *Python expects seconds* - well, if you use e.g. the `pandas` package, `pd.to_datetime(1571266800000000000)` works pretty well ;-)